# NestJS project fails to run on Windows but works on macOS

Tags: web, nestjs, backend, nodejs-server

I am attempting to run my small NestJS backend project on Windows, but I encountered an issue. This same project works normally on macOS

> freecodcamp@0.0.1 start:dev
> nest start --watch

/mnt/c/Users/anasm/OneDrive/Bureau/freecodcamp/node_modules/.bin/nest: 1: XSym: not found
/mnt/c/Users/anasm/OneDrive/Bureau/freecodcamp/node_modules/.bin/nest: 2: 0026: not found
/mnt/c/Users/anasm/OneDrive/Bureau/freecodcamp/node_modules/.bin/nest: 3: a7cc6068f8580a6e1bc7323401b10630: not found
/mnt/c/Users/anasm/OneDrive/Bureau/freecodcamp/node_modules/.bin/nest: 4: ../@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js: not found

Comment: did you shared the `node_modules` as well? because you shouldn't

Comment: Yes, I did. I transferred the same folder from macOS to my Windows system. What steps should I take next? Thank you for responding.

Comment: will you remove node_modules and install the packages again?

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` should be enough @aoustani

Comment: yes, it works, THANK YOU VERY MUCH